# Problem with WH_CALLWNDPROCRET

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am trying to catch messages from an application for which I have no source code.
I install a Windows hook like this:

```
hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, HookProcSetTextRet, hinst, threadID);
```

(The hhk variable is in shared data.)
I don't understand some of the behavior, though, specifically:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcSetTextRet(int code,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {  
PCWPRETSTRUCT st = (PCWPRETSTRUCT)lParam;
switch (HIWORD(st->wParam)) {
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        /*
        For lbn_xxx:
        wParam
        The low-order word is the list box identifier. 
        The high-order word is the notification message.

        lParam
        Handle to the list box. 
        */
            switch (HIWORD(st->wParam)) {
                case LBN_DBLCLK: {
                        log << L"\tWM_COMMAND ---  LBN_DBLCLK" << endl;
                    }
                    break;

                case LBN_SELCHANGE: {
                        log <<  L"\t+++ WM_COMMAND -LBN_SELCHANGE" << endl;
                        log << L"\t\tHandle to list box : " << st->lParam << endl;

                        HWND lbHwnd = (HWND) st->lParam;

                        res = SendMessage(lbHwnd, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
                        curSel = SendMessage(lbHwnd, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
                        log << L"\t\t\tLB_GETCURSEL returned : " << curSel << endl;
                        if (LB_ERR != curSel) {
                            res = SendMessage(lbHwnd, LB_GETTEXT, curSel,  
                                     (LPARAM)(LPTSTR) szBuf);
                                log << L"\t\tLB_GETTEXT returned : " << res <<                  
                                       L"\t\tszBuf: " << szBuf << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }  // WM_COMMAND
    /* snip */
}
return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

LBN_SELCHANGE is caught, but the value returned by LB_GETCURSEL and LB_GETTEXT is always the same.
LBN_DBLCLK is never caught.

There is similar inconsistnecy with other WM_ messages, as well.
Is the app itself somehow eating these messages?
Thanks for any ideas...

UPDATE:
Following a suggestion made below, I implemented a WH_GETMESSAGE hook.  It appears to be getting the doubleclick message from the listbox.
Unfortunately, LB_GETCOUNT returns the correct number, but LB_GETCURSEL always returns 0, and LB_GETTEXT still returns nothing...

```
    case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK: {
        const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        wchar_t titleBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        UINT curSel = LB_ERR;
        LRESULT res = LB_ERR;

        MSG * pMsg = (MSG *) lParam;
        HWND lbHwnd = pMsg->hwnd;

        log << L"\tGetMsgProc\t\tWM_LBUTTONDBLCLK" << endl;

        // Sanity check
        HWND parent = GetParent(lbHwnd);
        GetWindowText(parent, titleBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
        log << L"\t\tParent Title : " << titleBuffer << L"\tParent HWND : " << parent << endl;

        // Sanity check
        GetClassName(lbHwnd, titleBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
        log << L"\t\tList box class name: " << titleBuffer << L"\tList box hwnd: " << pMsg->hwnd << endl;

        res = SendMessage(lbHwnd, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
        if (LB_ERR != res) { log << L"\t\t\tLB_GETCOUNT : " << res << endl; }

        curSel = SendMessage(lbHwnd, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
        log << L"\t\t\tLB_GETCURSEL returned : " << curSel << endl;
        if (LB_ERR != curSel) {
            res = SendMessage(lbHwnd, LB_GETTEXT, curSel, (LPARAM)(LPTSTR) titleBuffer);
            if (LB_ERR == res ) { log << L"\t\t\tLB_GETTEXT Error -- invalid index" << endl; }
            else {
                log << L"\t\tLB_GETTEXT returned : " << res << L"\t\tszBuf: " << titleBuffer << endl;
            }
        }
        else { log << L"\t\tLB_GETCURSEL returned LB_ERR" << endl; }
    }
```

Comment: Is the list box multi or single selection? The documentation of the LB_GETCURSEL message quite clearly indicates that it shouldn't and won't work with multi-selection list boxes.

Comment: Pretty sure it is single select.  I'll see what happens with LB_GETSELCOUNT.
No idea why there is the LBN_SELCHANGED message, but not LBN_DBLCLK?

Comment: LB_GETSELCOUNT returns LB_ERR.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have spyxx.exe available on the target computer.  
The hook isn't getting WM_LBUTTON* messages, either.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found the documentation on window hooks severely lacking.

From their names, I think that the `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` hook would always get called somewhere after a corresponding `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook. The documentation of `SendWindowsHookEx` says about `WH_CALLWNDPROC`:

> Installs a hook procedure that monitors messages before the system sends them to the destination window procedure.

This suggests that it only gets messages that are *sent* (`SendMessage`, which calls the window procedure directly), not *posted* (`PostMessage`, which puts the message in the message queue).

If this is indeed the issue at hand, then you could try installing a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook along with your existing hook. This hook gets called when messages are removed from the message queue (by the window procedure, usually). Try and see if that hook catches the lost messages.

Comment: Sorry, I'm at a loss too. Maybe try disabling your `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` hook, see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

LBN_DBLCLK will not get sent if the list box doesn't have the LBS_NOTIFY state set on it.  Dunno why LB_GETCURSEL and LB_GETTEXT aren't working though ...